# Accessing method of different class in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to java and JSP, i have doubt about accessing the method of tag class. i have created 3 custom tags namely Primary, Secondary, Axis. so i can access

```
<pre:Primary>
  <pre:Axis/>
</pre:Primary>

<pre:Secondary>
<Pre:Axis/>
</pre:Secondary>
```

In Axis Tag class i have to access the parent methods, in this case primary, secondary is parent for Axis tag. In both parent class, i have method addItem(), i am calling the method as below in axis class.

```
 Object parent=null;
         try{
             parent = (PrimaryWrapper)getParent();
         }catch(Exception e){
            parent = (SecondaryWrapper)getParent();
         }
     parent.addItem(axisItem);
```

but this is shows error, "The method addItem(StringBuilder) is undefined for the type Object", i know in try, catch only the scope of parent is changing to primary/secondary, hence the error occurs. but i have to access the appropriate addItem method based on Primary, Secondary. is it Possible? Or i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you ever heard of `instanceof`?

Comment: Yes tried this too          
Object parent=getParent();
   if(parent instanceof  PrimaryWrapper){
    parent = (Primary)parent;
   }else
    parent = (Secondary)parent;

    parent.addItem(axisItem);

Comment: You have to make a common class that could be `Wrapper` and add a method `addItem` that you can override in each subclasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `parent` variable is of class `Object`, so anything you assign to it, you can only use the `Object`'s methods. I see basically two possible solutions.

Quick and dirty

```
Object parent = getParent();
if (parent instanceof PrimaryWrapper) {
  ((PrimaryWrapper) parent).addItem(axisItem);
} else if (parent instanceof SecondaryWrapper) {
  ((SecondaryWrapper) parent).addItem(axisItem);
} else {
  // log error?
}
```

Better - using Interface

```
// define an interface
public interface ItemContainer {
  void addItem(StringBuilder item);
}

// change your Wrappers to implement the interface, i.e.
public class PrimaryWrapper extends ... implements ItemContainer {
  // ... your code, just add @Override annotation to the addItem(...) method
}
// and
public class SecondaryWrapper extends ... implements ItemContainer {
  // ... your code, just add @Override annotation to the addItem(...) method
}

// and finally, fix the AxisTag code
ItemContainer parent = (ItemContainer) getParent();
parent.addItem(axisItem);
```

Or, as mentioned in comment from Hacketo, instead of creating and interface, you could create an common ancestor class (e.g. `Wrapper`) and implement the common methods there. The code of `AxisTag` would be similar to the above solution with interface.